# JS array send to php is returning as empty

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

In my form, I am pushing the form details to an array `myArray` when the submit button is clicked.

```
count ++;
var Array1 = new Array();
Array1['id'] = 6;    // form field values; as I am using DHTMLX I am just assigning a value in 
Array1['S_Id'] = 4;
Array1['amount'] = 66;
myArray[count] = Array1;
```

And these array values are added as rows to a DHTMLX grid. In order to save the form details to db, I want to send this array to PHP through AJAX. The array is like :

```
Object {1: Array[0]}
1: Array[0]
id: "6"
S_Id: "4"
amount: "66"
process: Array[2]
```

And I am converting this array to normal JS array using the following code:

```
 var array = $.map(myArray, function(value, index) {
        return [value];
 });
```

This is resulting in an array like:

```
[Array[0]]
0: Array[0]
id: "6"
S_Id: "4"
amount: "66"
process: Array[2]
```

Now I am sending this array to a PHP page through an AJAX request.

```
$.post('mypage.php',
     { filter : array },
     function(data) {
       console.log("result : "+data);
 });
```

In *mypage.php*, I am trying to print the result using `print_r($_REQUEST);` 
But it is returning empty data.

How can I get this array in PHP ? Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST['filter'])` You are sending a post. ^^

Comment: @NiCkNewman `$_REQUEST` contains the parameters from both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: I don't understand the original definition of your `myArray` object nor do I understand what you're attempting to do with the call to `$.map`. Can you just show `myArray` as JSON, ie `console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))`

Comment: @NiCkNewman..It is returning as result : NULL in my console.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to send a complex object to PHP (ie, not just scalar keys and values), you're probably better off sending it as JSON. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947483/submitting-json-data-via-jquery-ajax-post-to-php

Comment: Why `return [value]` instead of `return value`? You're adding an extra array level for no good reason.

Comment: Can you try passing a static string like this { filter : 'test' } and print in server. And tell whether it is getting?

Comment: @Phil..`console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))` is returning  `{"1":[]}`

Comment: Do you really have a parenthesis after `'mypage.php'`? That will end the function call, so `{ filter: array }` will not be the data argument.

Comment: Okay.. Go to the Network tab in chrome, click on your mypage.php request and show us a screenshot of the request headers. Is the data even being sent? (& Form Data)

Comment: @Jenz then where does all that other stuff come from; `id`, `S_Id`, `amount`, `process`, etc?

Comment: @Phil.. `myArray` is a dynamic array. When I print the array in JS, it is returning value.

Comment: @Jenz what you have at the top of your question doesn't make sense. It's not valid JavaScript or anything one could use to help debug your problem. Could you please show a **usable** example of what `myArray` looks like **just before you post it to your PHP script**. Also, what kind of data are you expecting on the PHP side?

Comment: @Jenz, convert your java-script array to json string and after send it

Comment: An array really isn't appropriate for what you're doing. Just use an object literal, eg `myArray.push({id: 6, S_Id: 4, amount: 66})`