# Angular js passing values from form to php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an angular form, which is sending values, but the phpfile is unable to print those values in database. If I put static values in php file, the values get inserted to the database. My php file is perfectly correct. Something, wrong with passing values from angular form to .php file. Kindly help.

FORM:

```
<form id="form1" post="">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="examplename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examplename" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleemail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleemail" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="examplecontact">Contact No.</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="examplecontact" placeholder="Enter your contact no." ng-model="contact">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitting()" >Submit</button>          

</form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller ('myCtrl',function($scope, $http){

    $scope.submitting = function(){
        var request = $http({ method: "post", url: "content/store.php",
        data: {name: $scope.name, email: $scope.email, contact: $scope.contact}
   });
        request.success(function (data) { alert("Successfully data entered! "); });
    }

}); 
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact  = $_POST['contact'];
echo ($name); 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, email, contact) VALUES ($name , $email, $contact)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

[image]

Comment: check your console for  request data

Comment: check the response tab if there is any error

Comment: Angular doesn't POST data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default which is the format PHP uses to populate `$_POST`. There's several other posts on StackOverflow dealing with this. I'll try and find a good one

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10947513/283366 if you want to handle the JSON payload in PHP