# AJAX post not sending data to laravel controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, laravel-5

The app i'm developing is under Laravel 5.0, i need to send some data from jquery **ajax** to a laravel **controller**, i've followed [this](http://tutsnare.com/post-data-using-ajax-in-laravel-5/) tutorial to post data using ajax, i've followed the steps and made the global configuration, so that i have a meta with the **csrf** token, when i send the post request to a url using ajax, it just sends the token!! but nothing of the data i give it to send!

Here's my ajax func (i'm using dummy data to test it):

```
        $.ajax( {
            url        : '/reservacion/paso-uno/enviar',
            method     : 'post',
            data       : { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
        } );
```

but when i **dd(\Request::all());** in the post func i only get the token, also if i check the headers form data i only get this:

[image: data sent through the post]

Here's a complete image of the headers:
[image: headers]

Here's the meta tag with the csrf:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{{ csrf_token() }}}"/>
```

And here's the global ajax setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
            });
```

**BIG UPDATE**

Don't know why, neither how, i guess it was just a cache problem, but having the above configuration it sends data, but that happens only when i have a `<input type='submit' >` and in jquery setup the click event, because if i setup it for the submit event it reloads the page with a query string in the browser path.

[image: post data]

Now the problem is that the function of the controller is not reached... when i click on the button nothing happens, data is send but it dont reaches laravel controller.

Comment: try to add dataType: 'html'

Comment: Are you trying to post raw JSON to your controller?

Comment: @hizbul25 noup, that didn't work

Comment: @Phil yes, but what i need now is to get the data to the controller, once there i'll see how to manipulate it...

Comment: @SetSailMedia yes maybe, but this time this isn't about Laravel, it's more an ajax thing, i don't really know why the hell it doesn't send the data!

Comment: i already did... sorry i'll update the post @SetSailMedia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88144/discussion-between-jonathan-s-and-set-sail-media).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting JSON data via JQuery ajax.post to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947483/submitting-json-data-via-jquery-ajax-post-to-php)

Answer (score 3):

### set meta-tag like follows

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

### set route

```
Route::get('/your/url/goes/here',
        [
        'uses' => 'TestController@testFunction'
        ]);
```

### set controller function

on top `use Input;`

```
public function iddtest()
{
print_r(Input::all());
}
```

### request like follows

```
$.ajax({
    data: {data1:'data1',data2:'data2'},
    url: '/your/url/goes/here',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### HTML Form

Somewhere in the form add the **CSRF Token** like this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

#### Route

Add a post route

```
Route::post('/path/to/ajax-form-process', 'FormController@processor');
```

#### Form process method

```
class FormController extends Controller{

  public function processor(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();

    //Do other processes

    return '200'; //Use any string that is appropriate
  }

}
```

#### jQuery Ajax

In your JS/jQuery script add the following

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'path/to/ajax-form-process',
  data: {
    data1: 'data1',
    data2: 'data2',
    data3: 'data3'
  },
  success: function(html){
    console.log(html);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the `_token` as part of your data set?

```
    $.ajax( {
        url        : '/reservacion/paso-uno/enviar',
        method     : 'post',
        data       : { "_token" : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content'), name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    } );
```

Comment: I did what you said but nothing happened... same result

Comment: Remove `$.ajaxSetup()` entry as well?

Comment: Yes, i did remove the ajaxSetup

Comment: Can you check again? It's POSTing properly at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLuvf7sw/

Comment: Noup, it's not posting and right now i'm facing a problem, when i click the button it reloads the page

Comment: If it's submitting the page (reloading the page) then you have broken JavaScript somewhere that's submitting your form in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your method to GET, in routes as well. Then grab the content with a Input::all();

Answer (score 0):

1. i do not understand your 'url' parameter in Ajax. Url should be
   like these: "http://serveradrress/yourroute"
2. On top of that
   where are your success, error and complete function in ajax ??
3. Are you submitting your request to your api or it is just internal
   request ??
4. Make sure you use post method :
   `Route::post('//your postroute','//controller@//method');`
5. In your
   controller you should have class and  :

   ```
   public function(Request $request){
       return response()->json(dd($request->all()));
   }
   ```