# Laravel 5 controller won't receive data from ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Ok guys, I'm stumped on this one. I am submitting a form using jQuery/Ajax to my Laravel 5 controller (Routing is working great, no problems). The controller is returning exactly what I am expecting except for the data from the form.

Here is some code.

**Form:**

```
    <form action="/candidateajax/add/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="candidate" id="addcand">
        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div>
        Name
        {!! Form::text('first_name', null, array('placeholder'=>'First Name')) !!}
        {!! Form::text('last_name', null, array('placeholder'=>'Last Name')) !!}
        </div>

        <div id="candimages">
        Image
        {!! Form::file('image', null) !!}
        </div>

        <div>
        Bio<br/>
        {!! Form::textarea('bio', null, array('placeholder'=>'Bio Text')) !!}
        </div>

        <div>
        Q&A<br/>
        {!! Form::textarea('qa', null, array('placeholder'=>'Q&A Text')) !!}
        </div>

        <div>
        Additional Info<br/>
        {!! Form::textarea('html', null, array('placeholder'=>'Additional Info Text')) !!}
        </div>

        <div>
        Party
        {!! Form::select('party', $parties) !!}
        </div>

        <div>
        <!--<button type="button" id="addcandbtn">Add Candidate</button>-->
        <button type="submit" id="addcandbtn">Add Candidate</button>
        </div>
        </form>

<div>
  Party
  {!! Form::select('party', $parties) !!}
</div>

<div>
    <!--<button type="button" id="addcandbtn">Add Candidate</button>-->
    <button type="submit" id="addcandbtn">Add Candidate</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$("#addcand").on('submit', function(e){

        var dataser = $("#addcand").serialize();
        console.log(dataser); // Proves that the serialized form has data

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax( {
      url: '/candidateajax/add/',
            data: dataser,
      type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            enctype:'multipart/form-data',
      success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
      },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
    });
    });
```

**Laravel Controller:**

```
public function createCandidateAjax(Request $request)
{
  $input = Input::all();
  return response()->json($input);
}
```

I've tried returning and vardumping both $input and $request. They are both coming in empty.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Any errors produced? And which exact version of Laravel...5.0, 5.1, 5.2?

Comment: have you checked your routes file? check if the request is properly routed to the controller and also check the error message which you are getting.

Comment: I guess you should remove action from your form, because your form has a button which is type submit and hence your form is posting data directly instead of ajax call

Comment: This code produces no errors for me and it returns exactly how it should except for being empty.  My routes are working fine. I made a method just for this Ajax request and it is connecting through perfectly fine.  I have also tried removing the action attribute from the form, but I still get the same results.

Comment: What exact version of Laravel? Wondering because `>= 5.2` has the web middleware that should be encapsulating this route since you're using the `csrf_token()` helper.

Comment: Also, have you tried the `meta` tag approach? See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33387660/2589179) as it parallels your issue.

Comment: First off, thanks a ton for helping!  The version of laravel that I am running is 5.1.2 and csrf_token is passing fine (which is wierd, because I can't print it out from the post anywhere). I've actually tried just printing out the $_POST info and I'm still not getting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Thanks for the help guys.  I figured out that my ajax request was being received as a GET request and not a POST request even though the Ajax method/type was set to POST and the form action was set to POST. When I removed the trailing "/" from the URL parameter, it sent as a POST just fine and worked as expected.

Heads up, on an ajax request to Laravel 5.1, I can't explain why Laravel 5.1 doesn't like the trailing "/", but it doesn't.