# Why does PHP does not receive the post request that made by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

This is my javascript code, the success event get executed. However the post array remains empty in php file.

```
    document.querySelector(".postButtons").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    const postID = e.target.value;
    if(e.target.id == "edit"){
        //Send post request to edit the post
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../edit.php',
            data: {postID : postID},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                window.location.href="../edit.php"
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }else if(e.target.id == "del"){
        //Send post request to delete the post
    }
})

  <?php
if(isset($_POST["postID"])){
    echo $_POST["postID"];
} 
?>
```

I have tried to log the variable to console in javascript, it seems working.The status code was 200 when i tried to return it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submitting JSON data via JQuery ajax.post to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947483/submitting-json-data-via-jquery-ajax-post-to-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location.href performs a regular GET request. Therefore, you do not see postID on the page. you can see the postID in the console in the request

But if you want to see the postID when the page reloads, then you need to send this request using the form, not the ajax.

```
<form action="../edit.php" method="POST" id="sendForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" id="postID">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

if(e.target.id == "edit"){
    $('#postID').val(postID);
    $('#sendForm').submit();
}
```